# How do I detect if a word is in a message discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make a bot that detects the word "burp" in every sentence, after it sees one, it'll send a message with "*weight* kg"

```
weight=0
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
  if ctx.content == 'burp':
    weight+=1
    await client.send_message(f"{weight}kg")
```

This code has many flaws, and one of them is weight+=1 referenced before assignment and the second one is that this only detects the message "burp", but not in a sentence. How do I change this?

Sorry if I'm bothering with a simple question, I'm new to discord.py

Comment: If you say `global weight` at the start of your function, it will establish that you're using the `weight` that you defined with `weight=0` earlier.

Comment: thanks, that helped the weight problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
if "burp" in ctx.content:
   # do something
```

Comment: it says AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'context'

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. I changed "context" to "content"

Comment: Why did you change it to "ctx.send()"? Your previous code for that looked fine, if not, try send() instead of send_message() (but with "client", not "ctx")

Comment: sorry i solved it by doing await ctx.channel.send , thanks anyways

Comment: Please search for duplicate questions before posting a FGITW answer.